# Why are there three parameters that can change during batch normalization according to MatConvNet implementation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, conv-neural-network

I was going through the MNIST example that comes with MatConvNet were they attempt to demonstrate how to use the API of their Batch Normalization. However if you take a look at the training file there is a line in `cnn_train.m` (in the `accumulate_gradients.m` function) as follows (I re-formated it to ease readability):

```
if j == 3 && strcmp(net.layers{l}.type, 'bnorm')
  %% special case for learning bnorm moments
  thisLR = net.layers{l}.learningRate(j) ;
  net.layers{l}.weights{j} = (1-thisLR) * net.layers{l}.weights{j} + (thisLR/batchSize) * res(l).dzdw{j} ;
```

where usually they would do a gradient descent update but instead do the mysterious above line.

**Why** do we need such a weird update?

According to [the original batch normalization paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf) [1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf) there are only **two** parameters to train, the scale $\gamma^{(k)}$ and the shift $\beta^{(k)}$. However, in that line of code they only do the mysterious line if `j==3` suggesting there is a 3rd parameter they update. To further support this claim if you inspect when they initialize the BN layer there is further evidence of the existence of this third parameter:

```
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function net = insertBnorm(net, l)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
assert(isfield(net.layers{l}, 'weights'));
ndim = size(net.layers{l}.weights{1}, 4);
layer = struct('type', 'bnorm', ...
               'weights', {{ones(ndim, 1, 'single'), zeros(ndim, 1, 'single')}}, ...
               'learningRate', [1 1 0.05], ...
               'weightDecay', [0 0]) ;
net.layers{l}.biases = [] ;
net.layers = horzcat(net.layers(1:l), layer, net.layers(l+1:end)) ;
```

note that even though there are only two matrices/tensors for the variable `weights` there is a third mysterious parameter for the learning rate which I am trying to figure out what it is.

Does anyone have an idea of what it is?

Furthermore, looking at [their library's documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_nnbnorm/) they have:

```
[DZDX,DZDG,DZDB] = VL_NNBNORM(X,G,B,DZDY)
```

which makes me think that the only thing could be a gradient with respect to the input X but that would make sense to me to use as an update rule.

Any idea of whats going on with this third mysterious index/parameter?

---

After thinking about it more, I have a feeling that it might have to do with updating the moments (since thats what the comment says). I am assuming that it has to do with updating the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma$. However, that doesn't make sense to me because I thought those depended on the population mean/std or the batch mean/std. Anyone can clarify?

Even if one has to update the moments, why does one have to update them with a **different** rule than the other parameters? If you look closely at that file, the rest of the parameters are updated using momentum but one is not.

---

[1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf): Ioffe S. and Szegedy C. (2015),
"Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing
Internal Covariate Shift",
*Proceedings of the 32nd International Conference on Machine Learning*, Lille, France, 2015.
Journal of Machine Learning Research: W&CP volume 37